# I2C SCL ground issue

Tags: i2c

I'm working on interfacing 2 development boards. I have control over the 1st development board. The 2nd development board is from a third party vendor.
My board (board 1) has a pull up of 3.9K and the third party vendor's board (2nd board) has a pullup of 1K.

The issue I'm facing, is that when both these boards are powered up separately, they boot up and behave correctly but board 2 doesn't boot when the bus is connected. I have access to a I2C protocol analyzer. Both board 1 and board 2 have accompanying daughter boards. With board x <=> daughter x , the I2C messages and voltage levels are fine.

When I tried to connect board 1 <=> board 2, board 2 doesn't boot. I have made sure that slave clocking is disabled on board 1. The requirement is that board 1 needs to be slave, and board 2 needs to be master.

What I have tried so far : 
With the I2C unplugged, I powered on board 1 and checked the SDA, SCL levels. They are at 3.3V. As soon as I plug the I2C connector to board 2 (it's still powered off), SCL and SDA get pulled low.

Now I powered on board 2 using the same power supply to ensure common ground.  The SDA line goes high immediately, but SCL remains low and there is no activity. Board 2 doesn't boot at all.

I have to stick to this order of power up, since the board 2 sends an I2C message only once a few seconds after power up (confirmed this using board 2 <=> daughter 2 with protocol analyzer).

I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your description is very confusing. Can you clarify what order of power up makes for a good working system? I know why you're having problems but I'm not clear what power up sequence you desire.

Comment: I need board 1 (slave) to be powered up and ready. When board 2 powers up it sends an i2c message (master), which I'm hoping board 1 will respond to(I have programmed the slave address in this). So board 1 powers up and then board 2.

Comment: Board 2's action, as described, really doesn't make sense. The only difference, per your testing seems to be the additional 3K9 of pull-up, in parallel with the 1K. I assume these are both pulled up to 3.3v. Have you tried without the 3K9 pull-ups? What exactly is board 2? Without more info, I don't think anyone can help you. Have you consulted with the board's manufacturer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem:

> I powered on board 1  [...] As soon as I plug the I2C connector to board 2 (it's still powered off), SCL and SDA get pulled low.

This is completely expected behaviour. You cannot connect both powered and unpowered devices to the same I<sup>2</sup>C bus, without additional precautions (or unless this is *explicitly* stated as being supported by that I<sup>2</sup>C device). In your case, `board 2` may also misbehave afterwards as you are likely to be exceeding the maximum allowed voltage connected to an unpowered MCU pin on `board 2`.

That is because you are *effectively* trying to power the MCU on (unpowered) `board 2` via its I<sup>2</sup>C bus pins, which are receiving power through the pull-up resistors on (powered) `board 1`.

#### Solution:

Use one of the various existing methods of I<sup>2</sup>C bus isolation between `board 1` and `board 2`.

Since you say that your setup allows you to connect the Gnd between the two boards, I don't see a *requirement* for the more expensive and complex galvanic isolation methods.

Instead the simple MOSFET-based circuit, often used as an I<sup>2</sup>C bus level-shifter from the old Philips (now NXP) [AppNote AN97055](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf) can be used. Using the simple circuit in section 2.3 of the datasheet, you connect `board 2` to the V<sub>DD</sub>1 side of the circuit:

---

[image: Figure 2 from Philips AppNote AN97055]

---

[Although not shown on the above circuit diagram, Gnd (0 V) must also be connected between the V<sub>DD</sub>1 and V<sub>DD</sub>2 sides.]

Using the above circuit, when the V<sub>DD</sub>1 (`board 2`) side is unpowered, it also receives no power via the I<sup>2</sup>C bus signals, even when the other V<sub>DD</sub>2 (`board 1`) side of the circuit *is* powered. Therefore it stops the problem explained above, as described in this excerpt from the Philips AppNote:

---

[image: Section 2.3.4 from Philips AppNote AN97055]

---

Various vendors sell I<sup>2</sup>C level-shifter PCBs with this simple circuit using suitable MOSFETs, if you don't have them yourself. However, note that such PCBs often have pull-up resistors fitted. Since you already have pull-ups installed, you must remove any duplicate pull-up resistors from wherever is easiest (probably by removing them from the additional PCB).

Comment: I managed to power on both boards simultaneously by connecting them to a regulated supply. I had to modify the driver on my board to get the communication going. Seems like board 2 needs the bus to be idle to boot up. It won't boot if it senses a different voltage on SDA, SCL.

Comment: @fastforward - "Seems like board 2 needs the bus to be idle to boot up." Waiting for an idle bus is not uncommon for master I2C firmware (perhaps the unknown firmware running on board 2 does not have a timeout for how long it waits?). Since you explained that your device (board 1) is configured as a slave, it should not drive SCL or SDA low, until addressed by the master (board 2).